# Add CPAN module without adding to ppm

Tags: perl, cpan

I am writing a piece of software that will be distributed to some developers. I am using libraries that are in CPAN, for example, Test::More.

How can I add these module to my software without adding them to ppm - reason behind this is that I do not want every other developer to install these modules into their ppm - it should work out of the box.

Any ideas?

Comment: I'd recommend using [Strawberry Perl](http://strawberryperl.com/) and not having to worry about ppm files.  Strawberry Perl is the superior Perl distribution for Windows.

Comment: How are you distributing your software? Have you looked at PAR? Why does installing a module mean that every other developer also has to install it?

Comment: havent looked at PAR ...

Comment: A possible disadvantage of using PAR is that it packages the Perl interpreter (or, at least, what is needed from the Perl interpreter) into your binary.  I've only tinkered with it, but when I created a "Hello, World!" binary via `PAR::Packer` the executable was somewhere around 22MB in size.  This may or may not be an issue for you.

Comment: @Jack Maney, ActivePerl does everything Strawberry does (provides and uses mingw, compatible with cpan) and more (provides pre-compiled modules, compatible with MS's compilers), so how can Strawberry possibly be better? Oh and, ActivePerl releases new version of Perl within a day or two. Strawberry is 13 months behind and counting. (It's behind by one version and three releases). If nothing changes for a few more months, the latest Strawberry will be an end-of-lifed-no-longer-supported version of Perl!

Comment: @ikegami - Since when has ActivePerl had CPAN support?  The last time I looked at it, the only way I could install a module was to use ppm files.  Strawberry Perl simply works out of the box.

Comment: @Jack Maney, IIRC, it has had it for the entire time I have been using Perl, and I started with 5.6.1. Support for MinGW came later, though. 5.10.1 is the oldest I have, and it installs mingw automatically if a compiler is needed.

Answer (score 1):

If your software is run from a particular location, installing them off that location will result in then being loaded from there first ('.' is first in the @INC path generally).  A better solution might be to:

```
use lib '/path/to/libraries';
```

which prepends that path to the local lib.  If that path is /path/to/your/software/libdir, and your install directory is static (or as above the running directory is always the same so the path can be relative...), it's easy.

More information on the lib module can be found [here](http://search.cpan.org/~smueller/lib-0.63/lib_pm.PL)

Comment: if, for example, I had to install MooseX::Declare ... how do I make a library out of it? is perl Makefile.pl enough?

Comment: You probably want the local::lib module.  It automates most of the stuff you'll want to do.  http://search.cpan.org/~apeiron/local-lib-1.008004/lib/local/lib.pm